# AJAX based email validator

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm using Ajax to check is if the fields in my registation form is valid or not.

My validate function:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function validate(field, query) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Creating Object
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () // Checking if readyState changes
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) // Validation Under Process 
            {
                document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
            }
            else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)  // Validation Completed
            {
                document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            else // If an error is encountered
            {
                document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Unknown Error Occurred. <a href='index.php'>Reload</a> the page.";
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "check.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```

And my check.php:

```
if ($field == "email") 
{
    $check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :query");
    $check->bindParam(':query', $query);
    $check->execute();
    $count = $check->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0)
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = true;</script>";
        echo "<font color=red>Email already exists</font>";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = false;</script>";
        echo "<font color=green>Email available</font>";
    }   
    if (!filter_var($query, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo "<font color=red><br />Please enter a valid Email</font>";
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = true;</script>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = false;</script>";
```

My `echo "<font color=red>Email already exists</font>";` work completely fine.

But as you can see, I also try to `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = false;</script>";`
when an email already exist in my database.

But somehow it doesn't work. I also tried to display:none instead of disabeling my button, but still with no result.

If i put `document.getElementById('regr_btn').disabled = true;` into the console of google chrome, then it works fine. So somehow my javascript isn't called.

I hope that you can help me out.

Comment: If your scripts are not being accessed then there is probably an error causing this problem. Press the F12 key and select the console tab to view any errors. BTW, the <font> element has been deprecated since HTML3 days.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your comment. I don't have any errors in my console.

Comment: I dont think you can execute a script ajax responce by default. You need to edit your ajax request for this and use Jquery's getScript() function. But then you will loose your html responces.

Comment: Any reason you're not using jQueries `.ajax()`? Makes handling Ajax so much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you I'd switch to using jQuery and simply passing a response back, then dealing with the response in your page. A short example of how I would do it:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/path/to/php/file.php',
    data: {email: $('#email-field').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if(response.count > 0) {
            $('#email-field-result').css('color', 'Red').text('E-mail already taken');
            $('#reg_btn').prop('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#email-field-result').css('color', 'Green').text('E-mail available');
            $('#reg_btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    }
});
```

And the PHP:

```
$query = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$check = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :query");
$check->bindParam(':query', $query);
$check->execute();
$count = $check->rowCount();

$return = array(
    'count'    => $count
);
echo json_encode($return);
```

If you use JSON to return your response it allows you to pass back complex responses from your PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use php only to return a response like: "Valid","Not valid", "Duplicate" and then in the javascript function executing the ajax call modify the DOM accordingly.

It is a nonsense (my opinion at least) to have php echoing some javascript.

Example:

```
if(data = "Valid") {
  $('#div_with_message').html('Email already exists');
}else{
  $('#reg_btn').attr('disabled',true);
}
```